# How to find a package once the corresponding external project is compiled?

Tags: build-automation, cmake

Is there a way to find a package only once an external project is compiled, since the package to find is created once this external project compiled ?

For now, I have:

```
include(ExternalProject)
externalproject_add(
  libantlr3c
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libantlr3c-3.1.3
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libantlr3c-3.1.3/configure -prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libantlr3c-3.1.3
  PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libantlr3c-3.1.3
  BUILD_COMMAND make
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
)

find_library(
  antlr3c
  libantlr3c.a
  HINTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libantlr3c-3.1.3
)
```

That fails, of course.

Thank you.

Comment: That seems hard since, as you noticed, the file doesn't exist until you build it. If your external project is simple enough, you might want to create a `CMakeLists.txt` for it.

Comment: No, I really need the external project, otherwise, the project is always considered as out of date. I need something like a lazy find_library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you control where the libraries are created, there's no need to use `find_library`. You can use `link_directories` directly. You'll probably want the same for the include directories to add the include paths to the compile line. Something like this ought to do it:

```
include(ExternalProject)
set(antlr3c_LIBRARIES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libantlr3c-3.1.3)
set(antlr3c_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libantlr3c-3.1.3/include)
externalproject_add(
  libantlr3c
  ....
)
link_directories(${antlr3c_LIBRARIES})
include_directories(${antlr3c_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(my_exe ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(my_exe antlr) # or antlr3c or whatever -lantlr is needed
```

Comment: I directly used link_libraries. Thank you !

Comment: This seems less than ideal if one is building many executables, not all of which depend on the external project libraries. It seems that it would be preferable to only add link/include directories on a per-executable basis. Is this not possible with CMake?